# Docker - Use IP instead of --link for communication

Tags: docker

I would like to ask, is it a good technique to use the IP address for communication between containers? I found about ambassador pattern and linking, but nothing about container's IP.

Is there any reason?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using tools like docker-compose/fig or just standalone containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It makes moving services difficult, and means that if you need to make a small change in one section, you may need to reboot entirely unrelated sections of your infrastructure.

The ambassador pattern is designed to try and make your infrastructure more portable and stable. This is a core containerization principle.